# Why Injected Provider - MetaMask not working

Tags: remix, metamask

Currently i m working in remix and metamask. Before 1 month the metamask account connected to the remix ide but now it is not connecting.
I tried updating the extension yet it is not working.
I also changed my browser, previously i was working in chrome now i changed to edge, then to it is not working.
I also tried creating new account instead of importing the old one, then also it is not connecting.
[image]
is there any other ways to make it work ?

network configuration
[image]
[image]

Comment: can you share the network configuration ? You will find it inside networks in metamask .

Comment: i have added in question section @GauravPant

Comment: everything seems to work fine . maybe the issue is with remix

Comment: I too think so @GauravPant , But i m continuing a project i left a month ago and i need to connect to calculate the transaction cost. That's what i asked. Thank you for answering.

Comment: if you know hardhat , see this https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/106535/111398 , maybe of some help

Comment: @GauravPant I will look into it. Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replying here instead of comment (level too low).
It seems that it is a remix issue, since they updated recently.

Here are possible solutions:

1. Connect to remix with other wallets (you will have to disable metamask in your plugins first)
2. Hard refresh remix (you may want to save your code locally before doing this) press `Ctrl+Shift+R` or `Ctrl+F5`
3. Use another browser to connect to remix

My fix for this situation was to finally learn how to use hardhat and foundry until a new stable remix version comes out. It gets also better to simulate tx cost with these tools.

Comment: I have already tried option 2 and 3, Its not working. I will check alternates for metamask or try using hardhat and foundry. Thank you for the valuable suggestions. @0xheartcode

Comment: I just cleared Cache from my system and it worked. I can now connect metamask account and remix from chrome. yet, will learn other solutions too. Thank you.

Comment: Glad I could help. So option 2 did not work but clearing the cache manually did ?

Comment: Ya, like manually i went to browser settings cleared catch and cookies then freshly opened everything and it worked. also i removed the metamask extension and again added the extension back.

Comment: CTRL F5 didn't help me. Just lauch a Docker image to operate my own Remix ... Guys... can you TEST your work before push it to all of us?

Answer (score 0):

Clear Cache files in your system and now try connecting metamask from remix. Save your work before clearing catch. It worked.
[image]